# Laravel 5.1.46 and response()->download() issue in firefox

Tags: laravel, firefox

I have the following code that updates a database before the return and download of the file for the user.

```
public function downloadFile(Request $request, $file_id) {
    $item = FolderItem::where('id', $file_id)->firstOrFail();

    DownloadedFiles::create([
        'user_id' => $request->user()->id,
        'file_id' => $item->id
    ]);

    return response()->download($item->location . $item->name);
}
```

The issue I'm having is that firefox on the first instance of the download will work fine, all the code will be run and the database will update, but from then on it wont, it just keeps ignoring that and downloading the file over and over.

In chrome, this works fine and I don't get the error. I'm not 100% sure but would firefox be caching the download or something? If so, are there any resources you can point me to to look this up to stop it happening?

I have searched to try and find something similar to this problem but the only question the same I can find is one on Laracasts but there has not been any answers (https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/firefox-and-response-download)

Thank you for any help, much appreciated.

Comment: Could it be possible that Firefox caches the result?

Comment: Will check that out, thanks.

Comment: I already had issue like that (or at least with download failing with firefox). The issue was the content type of the file not correctly set. Try playing with header `header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');`